# PostgreSQL denormalise query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using AWS redshift which use PostgreSQL as the sql language. I need some help in forming my query to denormalise data into a single row.

My Schema

```
Milestone
  -ItemId
  -LocationType //mapped to enum X, Y, Z
  -EventTime
```

Milestone could have three types of Location X, Y or Z. I want to denormalise this to one single row.

```
ItemId EventTime_X EventTime_Y EventTime_Z
```

I have tried something like this but its just taking forever to run.

```
select x.itemId, X.eventTime as EventTime_X, Y.eventTime as EventTime_Y, z.eventTime as EventTime_Z
from (select * from milestone where LocationType = 'X') as X
left outer join (select * from milestone where LocationType = 'Y') as Y on x.itemId=y.itemId
left outer join (select * from milestone where LocationType = 'Z') as Z on x.itemId=z.itemId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is one milestone for X, Y, and Z, you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select m.itemId,
       max(case when m.LocationType = 'X' then eventTime end) as eventTime_X,
       max(case when m.LocationType = 'Y' then eventTime end) as eventTime_Y,
       max(case when m.LocationType = 'Z' then eventTime end) as eventTime_Z
from Milestone m
where LocationType in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
group by m.itemId;
```